# Where do I store third party plugins when setting up gulp?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am learning to use Gulp for web development, and has successfully set it up to optimize my assets for a production website. My folder structure looks like:

```
|- app/
    |- less/
    |- img/
    ...
    |- plugins/
|- dist/
|- node_modules/
|- gulpfile.js
|- package.json
```

So currently my plugins are in the `/app` folder, whereas the whole site is being compiled in `/dist` for production. I could think of two options:

1. Move the `/plugins` folder outside the `/app` folder, however `.html` files inside the `dist` folder would have to link to files outside the `dist` in this case (e.g. `../plugins/...`) which doesn't seem logical.
2. Copy the whole `plugins` folder every time I compile the project with `gulp build` which seems to take a while. Not sure if that's a right way to do it.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You mean Gulp plugins or what else?

Comment: Are you compiling plugins folder?

Comment: @MaxArt, I mean third party plugins I also use like waypoints, some icon libraries, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little surprised that I couldn't find this in their docs, but third party plugins should be managed by using npm.

'npm install --save plugin-name'

Arguably you might use the --save-dev flag instead

EDIT

As for third party clientside libraries, you can still use npm, but some folks prefer to use bower or other tools instead.

It is generally considered best practice to not minify the third party scripts further, but instead you'd leave them in node_modules and make that servable, copy them to your dist folder or concatenate them with your other files as appropriate to your requirements.

As for how you let index.html know where to find them, that's going to be the same as how you do it for other files and depends on your workflow.  Some folks object all their scripts through a function on the server which either provides he location of the one concatenated and minified production file or an array of the separate source files and renders scripts for each as appropriate.

Comment: So if I, for example, want to use Owl carousel in my project, I run `npm install --save owl-carousel`, then how does my index.html know that it has  to load owl.carousel.min.js?

Comment: You copy the library using Gulp in the dist directory. But you might want to take advantage of the fact that it's available as a Node module, using `require` and a bundler like Browserify or Webpack.

Comment: Ah, I see that you're talking about third party clientside javascript.  I thought you were talking about gulp plugins.  I will amend.

Comment: Thanks. @MaxArt, so I should go with option 2) I guess (in case I don't want to go even deeper with Webpack etc.)